# how to make child in flex go full width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've started using flex and I love how it works.

I'm using flex layout and I want the `btn-group` class inside `dashboard-body` to go full width of the parent. Right now its width is equal to the width of both buttons together.

What I want to achieve here is adding space between both buttons also I don't want to use margin right or left. I want the `btn-group` div to have full width of its parent `dashboard-body` so I can use the flex property `align-content: space-between` to have enough space between both buttons.

Is there any better way other than adding margin/padding around buttons to do the same?

Thanks.

Here is the code:

```css
.dashboard-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
```

```html
<div class="dashboard-body">
  <p>You don't have any sales data.</p>
  <p>Please add a new book or upload CSVs.</p>

  <div class="btn-group">
    <a href="#">
      <input class="add-new-book-btn" type="submit" value="Add New Book">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <input class="add-new-book-btn" type="submit" value="Upload CSV">
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: `.btn-group { align-self:stretch; }` https://jsfiddle.net/bLaoh9td/

Comment: `align-content: space-between` not working in that case. Any solution for that.

Comment: You need to make the `.btn-group` a flex container as well: https://jsfiddle.net/bLaoh9td/1/ (BTW it's `justify-content`).

Comment: @vikrantnegi007 your example works well when "wide item" has to be _first_ or _last_ (by tweaking css a bit) element of the flexbox. However it doesn't seem to work when I want to make 'middle' item take full width of the flexbox. Is there a way to fix it? Or that's just the way flexbox works?

Comment: @DimitryK Can you create a jsfiddle for your case? I can help you out by looking at the code.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is the right way to achieve that:

```css
.dashboard-body{
  text-align:center;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.btn-group{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.btn-group a{
  flex:0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard-body">
  <p>You don't have any sales data.</p>
  <p>Please add a new book or upload CSVs.</p>

  <div class="btn-group">
    <a href="#">
      <input class="add-new-book-btn" type="submit" value="Add New Book">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <input class="add-new-book-btn" type="submit" value="Upload CSV">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i had to add width 100

Answer (score 24):

You can add `align-self:stretch` on the .btn-group. 
Here is a demo : https://jsfiddle.net/f5noh2q7/1/

Comment: Thanks so much, I was tearing my hair out! This one did what I wanted immediately with one row.

Comment: this was useful to do the opposite :)  I need to NOT let the children to take full width so I set it to `start`

Answer (score 10):

Just add this css rule:

```
flex: auto;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`align-items: stretch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) to *stretch* all children to full width (without centering them).

This approach is particularly suitable if you have many children that should all have the full width of the parent flex container.

```css
.dashboard-body {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: strech; /* <- strech children to full width */
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard-body">
  <p>You don't have any sales data.</p>
  <p>Please add a new book or upload CSVs.</p>

  <div class="btn-group">
    <a href="#">
      <input class="add-new-book-btn" type="submit" value="Add New Book">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <input class="add-new-book-btn" type="submit" value="Upload CSV">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```